# Item localized by the system or the user

Tags: web8.5, blueprint

I have a scenario, where I need to un-localize an item if it has been localized by the system. Is there a way to find out whether the item has been localized by the user or the system?

Comment: As per the other comments - the question needs a little more definition around the word "System", __for example, __ do you mean an event system functionality that impersonates a generic user or something like the TMS that uses a services - remembering that such services runs as a specific user that has specific Tridion privileges (so it's not the service localizing, it's the user registered to run the service and with access to Tridion)

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean localized by the system? Do you have some specific system user, which is also Tridion user? 
In any case, you can always check version 1 of localized Component and see which user did it. It MUST be Tridion user, so that answers your question.

Comment: Localized by the system, I meant to say  the item has been localized programmatically. So the issue is the version history shows the author name (Tridion user), even though it has been localized through programmatically and not manually by the user.

Comment: @PrashanthiPothuru Whether it is localized through an API call or though the UI, in the end it is exactly the same, and it is something which is done by a certain user (since the UI uses the API too). So obviously there isn't anything you can see about this. I think you should **edit** your question and supply some additional information, like what is using the API, are we talking about an event handler or a separate script etc. Then the answers can be focused on your actual question, how to distinguish between actions from the different or the same users (the latter will be almost impossible)

Answer (score 1):

Alternate approach: You can look at the "check-in" comment to figure out whether it is checked in by the user or the system, if the users are adding a check-in comment. This will allow you to differentiate between the commits.

When you localize, the comment will always have "localized from Publication..." as the message from the system and when the user checks it in and they are giving different comments, you can identify the same.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, look at the version history of the item and see who created the localized version. Here is a screenshot of Tridion 2013, but it's the same in Web 8.5.

[image]

Comment: hahahah @Nickoli, you beat me by a seconds :D